# Passing object from template tags to view

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Django version: 1.2.3

I want to pass Form object from template tag to dedicated view for this tag. My code is below:

```
    from django import template
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext, gettext_lazy as _
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.utils import simplejson 

    register = template.Library()

    ........

    @register.inclusion_tag('template.html', takes_context=True)
    def asset_diskencryption_settings(context, var1, form):

    context["form"] = form
    context["var1"] = var1

    return '' // Probably I have to use some method which allows me to return some variables to the template
```

In template.html I'd like to use form variable like i.e. {{form.password}}

Comment: Context is mutable, you don't need to call any method. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context

Comment: So what is wrong with my code? I try to assign form to the context, but in template.html form variable is empty...

Comment: As I see they call render method in a class, but I use function without class.

Answer (score 2):

To set a variable you should use an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags):

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_form(context, my_variable):
    form = Form() # do you stuff here
    return form
```

And use it like:

```
{% get_form 'my_variable' as form %}
{{ form.password }}
```

Comment: Assignment tag is not available in Django 1.2.3

Comment: i think dere is no assignment tag in django 1.2.X version .. it is in django 1.4+ only .. can you make me clear about this ..

Comment: Sorry my fault, didn't think of that... Maybe you can use a backport like this https://gist.github.com/gabrielhurley/1350641 as it may work with Django 1.2.3 as well...

Comment: Maybe, I hoped that there is something simpler:)

Comment: Can you give my some tips how I can import this feature?

Comment: The gist says it "To use, simply import this code in your project prior to using the ``register.assignment_tag``. In general, the top of your template tag python file would be a good place for the import.",the it adds the stuff to Django's `Library` so that you can use it like it is build in...

Comment: Ok, It probably works, but I am not able to load teamplate dedicated for tag. I need to call or render template in my new tag.